# Which parts are from Eminems real life?

Tags: biopic, 8-mile

In "[8 Mile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_Mile_%28film%29)" we saw how Bunny Rabbit got into the rapping gang and won the heart of millions of rap lovers. Now in Eminem's original life too similar thing happened. We know how Dr. Dre helped him getting into an industry which is dominated by mainly black people in USA. In fact, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem#1996.E2.80.9399%3a_Early_career.2C_Infinite.2C_and_The_Slim_Shady_LP) called the film semi-autobiographical. So I want to know which parts are direct picturisations of his real life?

Comment: *"and won the heart of millions of rap lovers"* - We don't really see him win the hearts of millions, just those at a single rap battle in Detroit.

Comment: @ChristianRau, Okay agreed. You can edit that part out. BDW was it okay to edit out the movie's name from the question's title? It was relevant IMO.

Comment: It wasn't entirely neccessary, but I needed to edit the question anyway, so just fixed it. The title is already in the tags and the question body, so there isn't really any ambiguity to be resolved by relevant information.

Answer (score 6):

The portions of the film which are direct reflections of Marshal Mathers (Eminem) life include:

1. He was raised in Detroit, Michigan for a portion of his life.
2. He was raised by his single mother in a series of lower income neighborhoods.
3. He was friends with local black rappers in the Detroit area.
4. He performed occasionally at local clubs and parties in the Detroit area.
5. He worked at area automotive plants before becoming a professional performer.
6. He had a troubled relationship with his girlfriend who later became the mother of his child.

The remainder of the story appears to have been created to fill in the narrative of the story and to make it appealing to viewers of the film.

Reference:

http://www.salon.com/2000/07/25/eminem_secrets/

http://www.today.com/id/27578186/